# King slime biome requirement

Tags: terraria

The [**King slime**](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/King_Slime) spawns instead of a slime in the outer part of the map, according to the wiki. Does the king slime also have a biome requirement, or does it just need a biome that spawns slimes that can be upgraded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, once you're in the eligible area for the King Slime to spawn, any slime has a chance to spawn as a King Slime.

So you're basically spot on - the only requirements that need to be fulfilled are

- be near "the border of the map"
- be in an area where slimes can spawn.

The second requirement could technically be interpreted as a "biome requirement" anyway.

Also The King™ needs enough space to spawn, obviously and trivially.

Comment: I asked the question because I could never get it to spawn in the jungle biome. (The edges always are either jungle or desert for some reason). Thanks for the answer. The space thing is a good point. Will need to terraform more. Accepted it. But would like proof of The King spawning in a non forest biome.

Comment: @Ids Heh, does anecdotal proof count? Anyway, hopefully someone can further prove/support what I said.

Comment: Well, if you have encountered it I'll believe you :). Pics are always better of course. (Or it didn't happen). I just could not get it to spawn, even with battle pots and a water candle.